# Ajax execute double request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two pages who share a single header, footer. First page is `wall.php` second page is `profile.php`. Inside `wall.php` am fetching post items from all my friends. Inside `profile.php` am fetching just my posts. Now all that am doing woth ajax jquery. Debuging code with fire bug when i call `wall.php` one ajax request is executed. When i go on `profile` page i have double the some ajax request executed. Check screenshot

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <!-- Get flash messages -->
        <?= $template->Flash()->render(); ?>

        <!-- Get content -->

        <?= $template->Content(); ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Custom.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   Post.loadAll(); // load all post when document is ready
}

var Post = {

    loadAll: function() {
        var list = $("div.post-list");

        $(".post-loader").show();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            cache: false,
            url: baseurl + "/post/list_post",
            success: function (r) {
                list.append(r); // add post on page
                $(".post-loader").hide();
            },
            error: function(response, s, e) {
                list.html(response.responseText);
            },
        });
    },
}
```

**Profile.php** and **Wall.php** have the some list for post listing

```
<!-- Profile posts -->
<div id="post-list" class="post-list">
   <?= if($posts): ?>
      <?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
            //.... post data(title, desc)
      <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

So problem is only on `profile.php` double request is executed. On `wall.php` all work good and just one request is executed.

Comment: Please show the generated web page so we can see the same thing the browser sees after it's been processed by the server.  You can get that from View/Source in the browser.

Comment: is there any additional includes, i.e. possibility to call `custom.min.js` twice in profile.php? btw you forgot to hide the hostname in network error line :) nice cat.